# Controlling the counter in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, counter

I made the counter and the counter is running smoothly.But I'll set up an if structure for my program. I want to add a parameter if the counter is 0, but how do I create the structure that controls the counter? I'd appreciate it if you could help clearly.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
Timer T=new Timer();
T.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {         
        @Override
        public void run() {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
            {
                @Override
                public void run()
                {
                    myTextView.setText("count="+count);
                    count++;                
                }
            });
        }
    }, 1000, 1000);


 onClick(View v)
 {
      //this is 'Pause' button click listener
      T.cancel();
 }
```

I hope I was able to help you.

Comment: It's a pleasure George. If this solved your problem, you can upvote the answer and mark it as cleared. Have a good time on your code !